# I want to automate the starting and ending date that are provided from the user on a excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I want to automate the starting and ending date that are provided from the user on a excel sheet. Below is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click() ; formatted

Dim startDate   As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B4").Value
endDate = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B6").Value

dbConnectStr = "Provider=xxdose;User Id=" & Uname
dbConnectStr1 = "Provider=xxdose;User Id=xxtrece ;Data Source=" & DSN

Worksheets("WorkFlow").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C30000").Clear

    'Set and Execute SQL Command

Set Sql.ActiveConnection = objmyconn
Sql.CommandText = "select system_date from syit_act_log where system_date between`enter code here` 'startDate' AND 'endDate' and action_id = 15 and log_desc not like '%svc_openlink_p%' order by system_date"
Sql.CommandType = adCmdText
Sql.Execute

Next
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").CopyFromRecordset (ds)
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Try formatting your start and end dates with # around them. Something like "...System_date >= #" & StartDate & "# ..."

Comment: Would I put this in the SQL query? You are saying something like this:  ...between 'System_date >= #"& startDate & AND 'System_date >=#"& endDate &.... @RyanWildry

Comment: You need to escape your variables for your sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot, as mentioned in my comment, you must escape the variables to add them as part of the SQL statement string you are building.

```
"select system_date from syit_act_log where system_date >= #" & StartDate & _
"# and system_date <= #" & EndDate & "# and action_id = 15 and log_desc not like '%svc_openlink_p%' order by system_date"
```

Comment: Every time I run it this tells me " Run time error Ora-00911: Invalid character" @ryanwildry

Comment: How should the Sql statement be formatted, say on SQL server? You want them to match. Through a debug.print to see the format you've got and how it should look.

Comment: I am imputing the date on excel and from there it's transferring it to the VBA. Could it be that because the format of the excel date is not the same as the SQL date and that is why we are getting this error? On excel the date is 03-01-16 but I believe SQL has to be 01-Mar-16